# how to subdomain based tornado routing?

Tags: python, routes, subdomain, tornado

I'm developing an application but this application run on two subdomain. This is classicaly.
admin.domain.com and www.domain.com

Tornado is loading routes on initialize time.

```
def __init__(self):
    client_routing = client.routing.Routing.get()
    admin_routing = admin.routing.Routing.get()
    setting = TornadoSettings.get()
    tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, client_routing , **setting)
```

But I want to load subdomain based routing. May be override rouing function and sperate routing handlers.

I don't know, how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Patterns passed to the Application constructor will apply to all domains.  To use separate routes per domain, pass an empty list to the constructor and use [Application.add_handlers](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.add_handlers) instead.  This is not very well documented but there is a simple example in the [Application class docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application)